# XML: layout_gravity ="right" not working for a TextView within a TableRow

Tags: xml, gravity

Sorry for all the folks who use gravity instead of layout_gravity or who
don't make the parent view wide enough.  I'm not making either of those mistakes
yet textView1 is pushed all the way to the left of the row and textView2 is push
right up against that.  As far as I know testView2 should be anchored to the 
right of the row, which is really the right of the entire screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/hwTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HW Part"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Make / Model"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vitalsDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Back" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

You probably found it out already, But if anyone else reads it...

Add `android:stretchColumns="1"` to the table Layout.